# I need to get the port of the chromedriver that I have instantiated in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, openfin

Here's my code to instantiate the webdriver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Now, I'd like to get the port on which the chromedriver has been started.
I actually am trying to get automation on OpenFin working and it uses RemoteWebDriver to drive their application using a ChromeDriver.

Here's the link to their Git : https://github.com/openfin/hello-openfin-selenium-java-example

The problem I'm facing is, as I myself have to run the tests on a remote machine, with multiple tests running in parallel, I would require the ability to run multiple instances of chromedriver on the remote machine and then pass its URL with the ports to each chromedriver instance to the RemoteWebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a ChromeDriverService to start the ChromeDriver

```
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
    .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("path/to/my/chromedriver"))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();
service.start();
```

Then using `service.getUrl();` one can easily get the URL which can be used to start the ChromeDriver (for RemoteWebDriver) `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());` or we may directly pass the service in the ChromeDriver constructor `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Selenium Grid to run parallel tests on remote machines.
So therefore you can send a http request to the grid and get the port of the browser. The resp variable will hold information about the node. like the ip and port.

```
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(GRID_IP, GRID_PORT);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        URL testSessionApi = new URL("http://" + GRID_IP + ":GRID_PORT/grid/api/testsession?session="
                + driver.getSessionId());
        BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest r = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST",
                testSessionApi.toExternalForm());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(host, r);
        String resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do but this returns only the information about the node and not the chromedriver instance which has been run. I would like to get the port through which I can connect to the chromeDriver

`newDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + GRID_IP + ":" + CHROMEDRIVER_PORT), capabilities);`

Answer (score -2):

Please login to the remote machine where the test needs to be executed and open the task manager to see the Port # on which the chromedriver is started

Hope this helps !!